# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent Only while Using FadingActionBar library?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fading

https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar  I am using this library to implement fading action bar in my fragment.(starts with a navigation drawer[Main Activity] , and
 on click of one  item in nav drawer it  opens main content.  A list fragment[Fragment 1] 
and on click on any item in list it opens another fragment which displays details
[Fragment 2] ) .

I click on item on nav drawer and then in 1st frag click on any list item and then it open 2 nd frag.Now
My apps crashes when i click back button when on 2nd Fragment.with  error

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent.You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

if in 1 st fragment i use in onCreateView

```
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.myxml,container,false);
```

It DOES NOT CRASH
 BUT if i use (below in OncreateView along with onAttach) as i have to implement fadingActionbarlibrary : IT CRASHES.

```
oncreateView(....){
super... 
view = mFadingHelper.createView(inflater);
return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);


    mFadingHelper = new FadingActionBarHelper()
            .actionBarBackground(R.drawable.ab_background)
            .headerLayout(R.layout.header_light)
            .contentLayout(R.layout.list_main_all)

            .lightActionBar(true);
    mFadingHelper.initActionBar(activity);
}
```

1 st FTRAG

```
        import java.util.List;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener;
        import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
        import android.view.InflateException;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ListView;

        import com.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar.FadingActionBarHelper;

        public class CommunityFragment extends ListFragment {
            View view;
            private FadingActionBarHelper mFadingHelper;
            List<list_object> lite = new FlowerData().getFlowers();

            public CommunityFragment() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                list_all_main_adapter adap = new list_all_main_adapter(getActivity(),
                        R.layout.list_view_custom_all, lite);
                setListAdapter(adap);

            }

            @Override
            public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
                list_click fragment = null;

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:

                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(getId(), new list_click(position), "Passing and replacing")
                                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
        //                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(new CommunityFragment()).commit();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(getId(), new list_click(position), "Passing and replacing")
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .commit();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(getId(), new list_click(position), "Passing and replacing")
                                .commit();

                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                view = mFadingHelper.createView(inflater);


                return view;
            }


            @Override
            public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
                super.onAttach(activity);


                mFadingHelper = new FadingActionBarHelper()
                        .actionBarBackground(R.drawable.ab_background)
                        .headerLayout(R.layout.header_light)
                        .contentLayout(R.layout.list_main_all)

                        .lightActionBar(true);
                mFadingHelper.initActionBar(activity);
            }

        }
```

2nd Fragment

```
            import android.app.ActionBar;
            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
            import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener;
            import android.view.LayoutInflater;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.ViewGroup;
            import android.widget.TextView;

            import com.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar.FadingActionBarHelper;

            public class list_click extends Fragment {
                public static int pos = 0;
                View v;

                public list_click() {

                }

              public list_click(int p) {
                  pos = p;

                }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.onlist_clik, container, false);
                    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                    tv.setText("Position " + pos);

                    return v;
                }


            }
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you please paste the other code of this file...and also the logcat to find out where exactly the issue is..

Comment: I posted it , In 1st frag i was changing oncreateView and adding method onAttach

Comment: anyone , could anybody spot the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue and found the following workaround:

I think this is a fool proof way to avoid re-inflating of the root view of the fragment:

```
private WeakReference<View> mRootView;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

/**
 * inflate the fragment layout , or use a previous one if already stored <br/>
 * WARNING: do not use in any function other than onCreateView
 * */
private View inflateRootView() {
    View rootView = mRootView == null ? null : mRootView.get();
    if (rootView != null) {
        final ViewParent parent = rootView.getParent();
        if (parent != null && parent instanceof ViewGroup)
            ((ViewGroup) parent).removeView(rootView);
        return rootView;
    }
    rootView = mFadingHelper.createView(mInflater);
    mRootView = new WeakReference<View>(rootView);
    return rootView;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mInflater=inflater!=null?inflater:LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    final View view = inflateRootView();
    ... //update your data on the views if needed
}
```

if your problem is really solved then please don't forget fit up arrow which describes that the solution is provided shows research efforts; it is useful and clear.